# Как реализовать в данном случае модель MVC PHP

Tags: php, mvc, оптимизация

Есть код:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['hgi4gfus83br6G7kihk'])
  {
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<?php include_once('blocks/bootstrap_header.php'); ?>


    <body>

<?php include_once('blocks/menu.php'); ?>

      <?php

      session_start();

      if ($_SESSION['hgi4gfus83br6G7kihk'])

      {

        include_once ('function.php');

        $db = new Database;

        $scan = new Scan;

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))

        {

            unset($_POST['submit']);

            $db->update('offices', $_POST, 'id_office = ' . $_GET['id']);

            header("Location: info.php?city=" . $_GET['city'] . "&id=" . $_GET['id']);

        }

        if (isset($_GET['city']) && isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['edit']))

        {

            echo '<form name="office" method="post">';

            echo '<table class="table">';

            foreach($db->select('offices', '*', '', "city_office='" . $_GET['city'] . "' AND " . "id_office=" . $_GET['id']) as $key => $value)

            {

                foreach($value as $key2 => $value2)

                {

                    echo '<tr>';

                    echo '<td>' . $key2 . '</td><td><input type="text" name="' . $key2 . '" value="' . $value2 . '"></td>';

                    echo '</tr>';

                }

            }

            echo '<tr>';

            echo '<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Записать"></td>';

            echo '</tr>';

            echo '</table>';

            echo '</form>';

        }
        elseif (isset($_GET['city']))
        {

            if (isset($_GET['id']))

            {

                echo '<table class="table">';

                echo '<tr>';

                echo '<th scope="col">Адрес</th>';

                echo '<th scope="col">Код</th>';

                echo '<th scope="col">Ноутбук</th>';

                //echo '<th scope="col">Teamviewer</th>';

                echo '<th scope="col">Mikrotik</th>';

                echo '<th scope="col">IP адрес</th>';

                echo '<th scope="col">VNCFA</th>';

                echo '<th scope="col">VNCVO</th>';

                echo '<th scope="col">VNCA</th>';

                echo '<th scope="col">Телефон</th>';

                echo '</tr>';

                foreach($db->select('offices', '*', '', "city_office='" . $_GET['city'] . "' AND " . "id_office=" . $_GET['id']) as $value)

                {
                    echo '<td>' . '<a class="first" href="http://' . substr_replace($value['ip_office'], 10, -1) . ':5901" target="_blank">' . $value['type_street_office'] . ' ' . $value['street_office'] . ' ' . 'дом' . ' ' . $value['house_office'] . '</a></td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $value['code_office'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $value['pwd_notebook_office'] . '</td>';
                    //echo '<td>' . $value['pwd_teamviewer_office'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $value['pwd_mikrotik_office'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . '<a href="http://' . $value['ip_office'] . '" target="_blank">' . $value['ip_office'] . '</a></td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $value['pwd_vnc_full_acces_office'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $value['pwd_vnc_view_only_office'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $value['pwd_vnc_administrator_office'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $value['telephone_office'] . '</td>';

                    echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="info.php?city=' . $_GET['city'] . '&id=' . $_GET['id'] . '&edit=true" role="button">Изменить</a>';

                }
              echo "</table>";
            if(isset($_POST['add'])){
              unset($_POST['add']);
              $db->insert('logs_offices', $_POST);
            }


            echo '<form class="form-inline" method="post">';
            echo '<div class="form-group mb-2">';
              echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $_GET['id'] . '" name="id_office_log_office">';
              echo '<input class="form-control" type="text" name="text_log_office">';
              echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="add" >Добавить комментарий</button>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</form>';

            echo '<table class="table">';
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th scope="col">Коментарий</th>';
                echo '<th scope="col">Время</th>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';
            echo '<tbody>';
            foreach ($db->select('offices, logs_offices', '*', '', 'id_office="' . $_GET['id'] . '" AND id_office_log_office=' . $_GET['id'], 'datetime_log_office DESC') as $val)
            {
              echo '<tr>';
              echo '<td>' . $val['text_log_office'] .  '</td>';
              echo '<td>' . $val['datetime_log_office'] .  '</td>';
              echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</tbody>';
            echo '</table>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<table class="table">';
                echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th scope="col">Номер отделения</th>';
                echo '<th scope="col">Адрес</th>';
                echo '<th scope="col">Телефон</th>';
                echo '</tr>';
                foreach($db->select('offices', '*', '', "city_office='" . $_GET['city'] . "'") as $value)
                {
                    echo '<tr>';
              echo '<td>' . $value['number_office'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . '<a class="first" href="info.php?city=' . $value['city_office'] . '&id=' . $value['id_office'] . '">' . $value['type_street_office'] . ' ' . $value['street_office'] . ' ' . 'дом' . ' ' . $value['house_office'] . '</a></td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $value['telephone_office'] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }

                echo "</table>";

            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<table class="table">';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th scope="col">Город</th>';
            echo '</tr>';
            foreach($db->select('offices', '*', '', '', 'city_office') as $value)
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td><a href="info.php?city=' . $value['city_office'] . '">' . $value['city_office'] . '</a></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }

            echo "</table>";
        }
      }
      else
      {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
      }

      ?>
    </body>

</html>

<?php
}
else
{
  header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Этот код выполняет следующую задачу. После авторизации я попадаю на некую страницу в которой вижу список городов. Кликнув по городу, я вижу список филиалов, кликнув по филиалу, я вижу данные по этому филиалу. Сейчас задался целью сменить дизайн и подвязать к сетке bootstrap, но написанный мной ранее код оказался ужасным. Проблему усугубляет еще и тот факт, что я никак не могу понять принципы MVC и применять их. Из-за этого такая каша получается. Каким образом его можно структурировать согласно шаблона проектирования MVC? Заранее спасибо за любую помощь. Если сможете на пальцах объяснить мне, как именно на данном примере этот паттерн применяется, то вообще цены Вам не будет :)

Comment: почитать про MVC и попробовать вникнуть...когда получиться - менять ваш код. Если не получится - юзать фреймверки, которые это делают за вас

Comment: Ты прав. Программист из меня плохой.

Comment: я не знаю кто такой "хороший" программист...каждый хорош в своем. НЕ кортайте себя и не падайте духом...побольше читайте, обучайтесь, практикуйтесь. Вы сейчас на 1 этапе развития личности....это когда человек понимает, что он инчего не стоит...многие этого не понимают за всю жизнь...так что лучше не плакаться, а поставить цель, и попытаться достичь.

Comment: начните создавать модели, в вашем случае это будет связка с PDO

Comment: если хотите реализовать свой микро сервис для этой странички, то сделайте мини контроллер - прежде вам нужно реализовать автозагрузку классов через spl_autoloader

Comment: В данном случае нужна 100% переделка. Эволюционировать это до MVC невозможно. Сейчас это как-то работает и есть какая-то логика. Возьмите и сделайте заново. Лучше сделать так: найдите понятный для себя урок. Выполните его. Поймите. Затем переделайте этот кусок.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Есть одна вещь, которую со временем приходится осознать всем пользователям пхп.
Каким бы простым на начальном этапе язык не казался, программирование в целом - это наука, такая же как физика или биология. Люди учатся программированию **годами**.

Да, какие-то примитивные вещи можно подхватить на лету, посмотрев пару видео в интернете и задав пару вопросов на форуме. Да, по началу привыкаешь, что все просто: надо поработать с БД? Опа, вот видео. Надо поработать с ХТМЛ? Опа, вот туториал. Надо поработать с MVC? Опа...

Но надо понимать, что просто будет только в начале. И есть темы, которые невозможно "объяснить на пальцах". Просто физически не хватит места в ограниченном по размеру ответе. В частности потому, что есть такое правило: чтобы понять ответ, надо уже знать его большую часть.

Чтобы не быть голословным, приведу небольшой список того, что понадобится для преобразования любого скрипта написанного в классическом спагетти стиле в MVC:

- Единая точка входа (когда к скриптам идет обращение не к каждому по отдельности напрямую, а все запросы обрабатываются единым скриптом)
- Роутер (скрипт который по запросу определяет, какой контроллер будет его обрабатывать)
- Контроллер (код, который принимает запрос и перенаправляет его в модель)
- Модель (которая реализует собственно логику приложения, я писал об этом [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/989552/179379))
- View (компонент, который отвечает за вывод ХТМЛ)

Все это вместе будет составлять довольно немаленький **фреймфорк**.  И в  рамках ответа на Стак оверфлоу просто невозможно рассказать, как сделать MVC фреймворк.

Поэтому MVC мы пока отложим в сторону и разберем более понятную концепцию - отделение бизнес-логики от представления.

Основная проблема этого кода в том, что в нем перемешана работа с БД и вывод данных. Вот для начала надо разделить их

- все данные получай не посередине формы, а заранее, до начала любого вывода
- вынеси разные показываемые страницы в отдельные файлы, и подключай через include
- выводи HTML как HTML, а не черех эхо в пхп
- **ради всего святого пиши код на каждой строчке, а не через одну**

таким образом твой код получится гораздо более компактным и управляемым.

Отдельным пунктом надо в ужасе выкинуть на свалку класс Database и для начала научиться работать с PDO через **подготовленные выражения**.

После того как сделаешь это, сможешь двигаться дальше по долгой дороге в сторону MVC

Comment: Приведите небольшой пример.

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/tech/tpl

Comment: опечатка *бизнес-логики

Comment: @Ипатьев, золотой ты человек. Долгих лет тебе и твоим близким. Ты правильно наставил меня. Поняв как отделить логику от отображения, а сразу же понял как работает модель MVC. И никаких примеров не нужно. Просто надо было понять, как отделить мой код от HTML. Спасибо еще раз, золотой ты человек!

Answer (score 1):

**MVC** - про то как разграничить архитектуру приложения.

На вашем примере у вас один жирный файл и это плохо, а почему? потому что человеку, который будет смотреть на ваш код придётся потратить около часа для дебага и понимании того, как это работает, зачем ему дебажить ваш код, когда можно сразу сделать понятно для всех, чтобы при прочтении названия функции или переменной было понятно, что она делает. Другой пример как уже написали выше html не хранят в выполняемой логике это плохая практика. Ещё пример, когда придётся добавить новую возможность в ваш код (например нужно получать ещё информацию из стороннего сервиса и отображать её ниже), сколько у вас займёт это время? а сколько бы заняло если будет понятно, какой бизнес объект за что отвечает и у кого какая зона ответственности, чтобы дальнейшая поддержка кода не съедала всё больше и больше времени, а наоборот экономила.

Итак, про **MVC**, как же правильно построить начальную архитектуру.

Обозначим, что

**M - Model** отвечает у нас за всю выполняемую бизнес-логику, будь то запрос в БД, сортировка списка, хранение данных в сессии, работа с данными из $_GET $_POST.

**V - View** отвечает за отображение html.

**C - Controller** отвечает за управление всего этого в том числе вызов бизнес-логики и передача данных во view

Вы можете попробовать разнести этот огромный кусок кода по разным файлам в своей структуре папок как пример:

модели в - **app/models/**

контроллеры в - **app/controllers/**

вьюшки в - **app/views/**

Я постарался объяснить своё виденье MVC, возможно у более опытных будут вопросы, но я попытался не трогать принципы проектирования и описать всё понятным языком для новичка.