# Куда размещать бизнес логику приложения laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, архитектура

У меня вопрос более общего характера, с которым я столкнулся в процессе разработки приложения.

Где нужно размещать бизнес логику приложения? 
Перечитал разные статьи и все они расходятся во мнениях. Одни пишут что в моделях, следуя принципу "худых" контроллеров, другие пишут, что модели отвечают только за работу с полями БД.

Для примера, в моем проекте (интернет-магазин) присутствует фильтр товаров. Вот он используется (пока что) только в контроллере категорий, работает только с таблицами продуктов и параметров. Я выделил класс фильтра в отдельную директорию именуемую Filters (да, там их несколько разных).

Вопрос:

1. На сколько правильно я сделал (и правильно ли вообще)?
2. Все же, куда помещать такие вот моменты бизнес логики?

Comment: Бизнес логика априори контроллеры. Модели - работа с бд. Как в первые не стоит совать запросы, так и во второе не стоит заниматься "обработкой"

Comment: `Перечитал разные статьи и все они расходятся во мнениях` - да здесь будет тоже самое: что ни ответ, то мнение. Тема как повод потрести воздухом.

Comment: Laravel - это всего навсего инструмент для разработки, что и где размещать зависит только от тебя (каждый по разному воспринимает абстракцию).  Создавай свои фасады, выноси в отдельные файлы, делай код более простым. Ведь лучше открыть один файл с классом `Filter` чем искать по всему проекту остальные.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы. Учту.

Comment: @InDevX в любой литературе по MVC (да даже на той же википедии) пишут, что контроллеры обязаны быть как можно более «тонкими» и категорически ни в коем случае не должны содержать бизнес-логику. Бизнес-логика — или в моделях (про бд это вы сами выдумали), или где-то между контроллерами и моделями (если вам уж очень хочется оставить модели только для бд)

Comment: @andreymal википедия не лучший источник для изучения) а так-то я отчасти согласен. Тут важно что именно вы вкладываете в понятие бизнес-логики.. Для кого-то это абсолютно все события (процессы и т.п..) связанные с приложением, а для кого-то это лишь "поведенческие" факторы. На этот счёт нет единой точки зрения, нет стандарта, как такового. Для меня бизнес-логика это алгоритм решения какой-то задачи.

Comment: Твой вариант норм - использование сервис-класса. Можно в модели насоздовать `scope*` методов и комбинировать их в контроллере - тоже приемлимый вариант

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хороший вопрос, и, как показывают комментарии, далеко не всем понятный.

Главное, что надо понимать, услышав аббревиатуру MVC - что термин Model носит двусмысленный характер. Он может означать как всю бизнес логику приложения (правильно), так "только работу с полями БД" (массовое застарелое заблуждение пользователей похапе). Как только в голове устаканивается правильный вариант, тут же все встает на свои места. Главное тут понимать, что модель, это не класс для работы с БД, а вся бизнес-логика приложения, разумеется, разбитая на множество слоев и уровней.

Вот [короткое пояснение всей системы](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/mvc), на английском, так что перескажу своими словами. Очень хорошо эту тему также раскрывает Дмитрий Елисеев в своих докладах на конференциях и обучающих видео - настоятельно рекомендую.

В двух словах, есть приложение и есть *интерфейсы*. Приложение одно - интрефейсов много. В докладе на PHPRussia Дмитрий насчитал 5, и это еще не предел:

- веб-контроллер, который рисует форму
- REST контроллер, который отдает тупо JSON
- вебхук контроллер, который принимает данные из CRM
- консольная утилита
- сервис очередей

ВСЕ эти интерфейсы могут быть использованы для интеракции с внешним миром и выполнения одной и той же задачи. Именно поэтому никакой, ни малейшей бизнес-логики в них быть не должно, или тут же начнется дублирование кода. Поэтому надо отличать интерфейсы от собственно приложения.

- Контроллер. Это просто *интерфейс*. Прислуга. Взять данные из НТТР запроса и передать их в соответствующий метод *настоящей* модели. Чисто "подай-принеси". Если какая логика в контроллере есть - то только связанная с обработкой формы или запроса. Скажем, проверить заполненность полей, совпадение паролей и пр. После получения ответа из модели отправить нужные НТТР заголовки - куки, сессия, локейшен - вот это вот всё.
- Модель. Состоит из нескольких слоев

  - сервис или хелпер. Тот код, который обычно пишется в толстом контроллере. Собственно код приложения, без упора на работу с БД. К примеру, если мы хотим зарегистрировать пользователя, то у нас должен быть сервисный слой Пользователь, у которого есть метод register(). И вот этот вот метод мы и вызываем хоть из контроллера, хоть из консольной утилиты, хоть из вебхука.
  - слои для работы с БД
  - их может быть много. Может быть вырожденная "модель" (в плохом смысле этого слова), тупо класс, в методах которого написаны SQL запросы на все случаи жизни.
  - может быть целая иерархия - для простых запросов ORM, для более сложных - репозиторий.

Если говорить о конкретно этом случае, то фильтры - это работа контроллера, поскольку это НТТР запрос. Дело контроллера обработать все поля, вытащить из них осмысленную информацию и запросить метод сервиса товаров с теми данными, по которым надо делать запрос.

Разумеется, если работа с фильтрами может производиться в разных контроллерах, то разумно вынести ее в отдельный сервис. Соответственно, в контроллере будет два обращения  - один к сервису фильтров, второй - к модели.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!