# Где размещать switch case в MVC (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, mvc, solid

У меня есть метод в контроллере Laravel, который обрабатывает добавление сообщения разных типов. Из этого я понимаю, что саму обработку каждого типа сообщение нужно разместить в Service классах, но где разместить сам switch case для распределения по типам сообщений?

Первый вариант - создать отдельный класс в Service классах, который уже будет перенаправлять запрос на классы обработчики для каждого типа. Второй вариант, т.к. я стараюсь размещать все метод связанные с сущностью в модели, то разместить switch case в методе в модели. Про размещение всех методов связанных с моделью прочитал тут: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/987692/Куда-размещать-бизнес-логику-приложения-laravel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/987692/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-laravel)